# Sort referenced Schema by created at date in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

following Problem, In my app i have Posts and each post can have an array of comments.
I am trying to sort the comments by their date. I already searched for and already tried out any of the solutions but none of them worked for me.

**My attempts not working:**

```
const post = await Post.findById(id)
    .populate({
        path: 'comments',
        options: { sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
    })

const post = await Post.findById(id)
        .sort({ 'comments.createdAt': -1 })
```

In my Post Model if reference the Comments model like following:

**COMMENT SCHEMA**

```
    {
        comment: { type: String, required: true },
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User',
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)
```

**POST MODEL:**

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User',
        },
        image: {
            type: String,
        },
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        workout: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Workout',
        },
        comments: [commentSchema],
        numComments: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 0,
        },
        likes: [likeSchema],
        numLikes: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 0,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
)
```

Thx for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is where you want to sort happen, to sort it on client side the easiest solution will be in place sorting of array `comments`, since you are not referencing another schema document with `ref` there is no need for `populate` (lookup), just write another `then` function like this:

```
    const post = await Post.findById(p._id).then(result => {
        result.comments.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt > b.createdAt ? -1 : 1);
        return result;
    })
```

To sort while fetching you should use the aggregate model function, and use the pattern of pipe stages: $match, $unwind, $sort, $group. But it is a way complicated.

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks a lot. Are benefits of using the aggreagte model function huge? Instead of sorting the result?

Comment: In my opinion, it depends on how many comments are you expecting to have? Sorting on the client-side of large arrays (record numbers measured in 100's or 1000's) is not advisable. I have assumed, based on your schema, that the number of comments is pretty low. Just remember node is a single thread and `sort` is synchronous. That is the main disadvantage of client-side sorting.